# Is there a whitelist for internet access in parental controls?

Tags: permissions, internet-browser

For young kids I think it is easier to start with only a couple of open web sites.

Comment: All I could find on the subject is [this](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-parental-controls/issues/27) GitHub issue. The good news is that it's still open, and there is a bounty set on implementing it.